# Enumerating a set of positive reals with a unique, strictly increasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^+$ be a set of positive real numbers such that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, the set $X \cap [0, x]$ is finite. Unless I am sorely mistaken, this set can be enumerated by one and only one sequence $z$ such that:

- Every element of $X$ appears in $z$;
- $z$ is strictly increasing.

I need to use this in a paper I'm writing, and I would like to avoid dragging the reader through a lengthy proof unless strictly necessary. Attention is a limited resource and I wouldn't want to waste it proving fundamentals! As such I am wondering:

- This sounds like a relatively straightforward result that should exist somewhere in literature. Is there anything I can reference to avoid proving the result myself?
- If not, what is a quick and simple way to prove this? I think I could come up with a proof but everything I write feels unnecessarily convoluted.